# why using += at the end of makefile can't work but at beginning can do?

Tags: c++, makefile

[image]

I used the += in makefile and try to add more compiled files:

make the left file can work rightly: compile 4 .cpp file.

but make the right file can't work, it only compile the main.o and xmlutil.o. **thus, echo $(OBJS) in echomsg can print 4 .o.**

So what's the root cause?

Comment: The one of the right fails, because OBJS is used prior to the += which means that the compilation rule does not yet contain the new files.

Comment: @Chris, I can't catch your meaning, why echo %(OBJS) can print 4 files, but as dependent target, it can't .

Comment: Looks like you have a trailing `\` on the second line of the `OBJS +=`. Do you? If so the first case has a blank line next (so adds nothing), while the last line is an end of file. I can't really read the image...

Comment: @TimothyBrown no trailing.

Comment: As `make` reads the `makefile`, it expands the RHS of rules lines (such as `${TARGET}: ${OBJS}`) with the current value of `${OBJS}`.  When the macro is used in a command, it is expanded when the command is executed, so the `echo ${OBJS}` gets the value from the end of the file because it is not expanded until after the whole file has been read.  Also, it would be far preferable if you didn't use screen shots but showed the text of the two makefiles.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler，Many thanks to you!, ps: what's RHS?

Comment: RHS = right-hand side (and LHS = left-hand side; but LHR is London Heathrow :D ).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do you mean that make read rule lines before complete read all file content? so the macro taking will take two phases: one is read rule, the other is executing command?

Comment: Yes.  At least, that's the classic way it is done.  I've not looked at GNU `make` source code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you give some reference or more infos about this rule, I can't found any one. Thank you very much,What's more, you can provide this info as answer so that I can accept the answer,3ks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `make` reads the `makefile`, it expands the RHS<sup>*</sup> of rules lines (the `${OBJS}` in lines such as `${TARGET}: ${OBJS}`) with the current value of `${OBJS}`. When the macro is used in a command, it is expanded when the command is executed, so the `echo ${OBJS}` gets the value from the end of the file because it is not expanded until after the whole file has been read.

This behaviour is specified for POSIX [`make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) in the section about 'Macros':

> #### Macros
>
> …
>
> Macros can appear anywhere in the makefile. Macro expansions using the forms `$(string1)` or `${string1}` shall be replaced by `string2`, as follows:
>
> - Macros in target lines shall be evaluated when the target line is read.
> - Macros in `makefile` command lines shall be evaluated when the command is executed.
> - Macros in the string before the `<equals-sign>` in a macro definition shall be evaluated when the macro assignment is made.
> - Macros after the `<equals-sign>` in a macro definition shall not be evaluated until the defined macro is used in a rule or command, or before the `<equals-sign>` in a macro definition.

The first bullet defines the behaviour I stated.

There's an interesting comment earlier in the specification (under 'Makefile syntax')

> Macros can also be defined more than once, and the value of the macro is specified in Macros.

---

<sup>* RHS = right-hand side</sup>

Comment: 3ks very much, can you help to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300006/why-popup-no-rule-to-make-target-it-when-make-file

Comment: when reading rule, do you mean it doesn't finish read for all content of file, only content before the rule line? 3ks, other boy asked me again.