# Why the error "no rule to make target 'it'" when the makefile is like this?

Tags: makefile

```
[root@localhost src]# cat Tmake

check=love

check+=it

all:    $(check)


love:
        echo "love"

loveit:
        echo "loveit"


[root@localhost src]# make -f Tmake
echo "love"
love
make: *** No rule to make target `it', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Why can't it find it? It doesn't look for `love` or `loveit` but `it`; I can't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `check` ends up with the value `love it`; the `+=` operation adds the new word after a blank, regardless of whether there are spaces around the `+=` operator.

The `all` rule therefore depends on `love` and `it`.  You've told it how to make `love`, but you've not told it how to make `it` (and presumably you have no files `it.*` that can be compiled to create `it` using inference rules), so you get the error message.

You could demonstrate this by having a rule:

```
check:
    @echo $(check)
```

before the `all` rule.  This would show the space between `love` and `it`.

---

### GNU Make (3.82) Reference Manual

> #### 6.6 Appending More Text to Variables
>
> Often it is useful to add more text to the value of a variable already defined. You do this
>   with a line containing `+=`, like this:
>
> ```
> objects += another.o
> ```
>
> This takes the value of the variable `objects`, and adds the text `another.o` to it (preceded
>   by a single space).

Note that there is no point in looking in the POSIX specification for this since `+=` is an extension in GNU `make`.

Comment: you are right, but I think the state : "the += operation adds the new word after a blank, regardless of whether there are spaces around the += operator" is too strange, is there any official articles talked it?Many thanks to you!

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Appending: _This takes the value of the variable objects, and adds the text ‘another.o’ to it **(preceded by a single space)**._